# How can I recast a CNF expression to 3-CNF?

Tags: cnf

I have a CNF expression like this and I want recast it to 3-CNF:

```
(a+b+c+d)(~a)(~b+d)(a+b+~d)
```

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: You might be interested in the answer I just posted for this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27588951/2213720

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [3-CNF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56369/can-someone-please-explain-3-cnf-for-me) is a [Conjunctive Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) where all clauses have three or less literals. To obtain such a form for your expression, you could translate the expression into a nested Boolean expression where all operators (and, or) have two operands:

```
t1a = (a+b)
t1b = (c+d)
t1 = t1a + t1b
t2 = (~a)
t3 = (~b+d)
t4a = (a+b)
t4 = t4a + ~d
t5a = t1 t2
t5b = t3 t4
t5 = t5a t5b
```

You can directly translate this nested expression into a set of 3-CNF clauses.

**Minimized solution:**

```
(~a)(~b + d)(b + ~d)(c + d)
```

as suggested by [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a%20or%20b%20or%20c%20or%20d%29%20and%20%28not%20a%29%20and%20%28%28not%20b%29%20or%20d%29%20and%20%28a%20or%20b%20or%20not%20d%29) is a `3-CNF` of your expression as it does not contain longer clauses.

For small cases, you could fill a truth table. Look at all rows with output 0 and find minterms covering all these rows. If you then invert all literals in the minterms, you have a `CNF`. In case clauses have more than 3 literals, they can be broken up into two or more shorter clauses by introducing intermediate variables. The widely used procedure for that is called [Tseitin Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseitin_transformation) or Tseitin Encoding.